# Add a new template type to existing bucket

Tags: templates, buckets

I'm going to explain the issue with a quick example.

I have a Folder item based on 'Folder Template', which is bucketable. I have 2 other templates - Page Template 1 and Page Template 2. The items based on Page Template 1 and Page Template 2, are actually within the Folder item as bucketable items.

I created Page Template 3 and tried to include it in Folder item as a bucketable item but whenever I create this item, it gets created as a regular item and not as a bucketable item.

Page Template 3 is essentially a copy of Page Template 2, with a few different components on it but for some reason acts differently.

Has anyone noticed this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have set `Is Bucketable` on the standard values for templates that you want to be able to store *inside* a bucket.

A bucket can have items based on many number of content templates.

For your `Folder Template` to be an item bucket, you have to select it and click on the `Bucket` button in the `Configuration` ribbon. Once it is a bucket, if you have correctly set `Is Bucketable` to true on the standard values of `Page Template 3` it will be stored as a bucketable item.

Comment: Page Template 3 has Bucketable as true and Is Bucket as false, same as Page Template 2. But still the issue persists.

Comment: Is that on the template or the template std values?

Comment: standard values of page template 3

Comment: I figured it out. For some reason the branch did not get that setting propagated from the standard values of page 3. Once I fixed it all worked.